# Deploy Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 to Multiple Servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, .net-4.0

Does anyone know of a way to deploy the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 to multiple Windows 2008 R2 Servers.  I am only finding an .exe download...

Answer (score 0):

The SDK also comes as an iso [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35aeda01-421d-4ba5-b44b-543dc8c33a20&displaylang=en).

However, as far as I understand your question, you have more of a centralized installation problem. In that case, you'll be better off with the exe. Just store it on a share available to all servers and remote exec the command line with Powershell remoting (or plain old WMI calls but it is a lot trickier). The whole process can be automated by tools such as SCCM.